# Equivalent of Bon Voyage to those staying behind?

Tags: idioms, adjectives

I am organizing some farewell drinks as we are leaving.  I am wondering what is the equivalent of Bon Voyage to those staying behind, i.e. I am trying to say Bon Voyage drinks.

Maybe something like parting drinks would suffice but it doesn't convey any sense of levity, joviality or good wishes.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I would simply use the French for "Good stay".

Comment: Bon Restez  doesn't have the same ring to it.  As you know Bon Voyage is in common use in English, whereas Bon Restez doesn't exist as a colloquialism.

Comment: Your own term "farewell drinks" works.

Comment: Au revoir, "until we meet again."

Comment: “Never say goodbye, say farewell.” ― Anonymous . So toast ... "farewell to all". ( with a tip 'o the hat to @Lawrence

Comment: 'A bientôt' - See you soon (literally "until soon").